# isolated storage in windows phone developement

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Im using VS to develop a windows phone app. Im doing it wp8 but it doesnt matter because it the code works for 7 too. Anyway, I have a text box and a button. When the text from the text box is entered, and the button is clicked it adds that to isolated storage.
On my other page, I have a textblock. Which should display what I wrote in the text box. It does work, but first let me sho you my code.

```
if (appsettings.Contains("name"))
{
   appsettings.Remove("name");
   appsettings.Add("name", TitleTextBox.Text); //rename if already exists
}
```

and then the second page that collects the info is below.

```
if (appsettings.Contains("name"))
{
   string content = appsettings["name"].ToString(); //converts to string
   titleTextBlock.Text = content; //shows title in text block 
}
```

The problem is, the "name" works. However, if I call it ANYTHING else it does not. I want to add a different name because i want to be able to input two lots. For example two text box's and then when you press the button and go to the other page, it has two textblocks displaying each string in each one. I can't seem to do this because only "name" works. Ive changed it to other names and it doesnt work. Does anyone know why?

Comment: What do you mean ANYTHING? Have you added a key to dictionary before using it?

Comment: for example, if i change it to;
if (appsettings.Contains("title"))
     {
       appsettings.Remove("title");
       appsettings.Add("title", TitleTextBox.Text);
     }   will not work

Comment: Probably not. But im not aware of doing it before for the "name" either

Comment: There is no need to remove key if you want to change it - see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IsolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) works as a Dictionary. If you want to acces a specific key it should exist in the Dictionary.

If you try to change the value that already exists you can do like this:

```
if (appSettings.Contains("key")) appSettings["key"] = "new value";
else appSettings.Add("key", "new value");
```

Don't also forget to save your appSettings:

```
appSettings.Save();
```

And also according to your code - in ISS you can put not only `string` - it can be any object, if you want to get it, you should make a cast or use `as`:

```
string content = (string)appsettings["name"]; //converts to string
string content = appsettings["name"] as string;
```

**EDIT** - after comments, rebuild once more

If you want to have a to-do-list and you know that every task has its specific title, description and time then I would advise to create a special class for this, for example:

```
public class myTodo
{
    public string TaskTitle { get; set; }
    public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ElapsedTime { get; set; }
}
```

I used `TimeSpan` because I think it's easier to manage Time with it. Then if you want to Save/Load your `myTodo` you can do like this:

```
// create an example of your task
myTodo newTask = new myTodo() { TaskTitle = "Clean", TaskDescription = "Clean room", ElapsedTime = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0) };

// add it to ISS and save
if (appSettings.Contains("firatTask")) appSettings["firatTask"] = newTask;
else appSettings.Add("firatTask", newTask);
appSettings.Save();

// try to load
myTodo read = appSettings["firatTask"] as myTodo;
```

You can access your item like this:

```
read.Title = TitleTextBox.Text; // and so on
```

Consider also making a `List<myToDo>` and be aware that ISS shoul also handle this:

```
List<myTodo> listJob = new List<myTodo>();
listJob.Add(firstTask); // firstTask is myToDo
listJob.Add(secondTask); // secondTask is myToDo

if (appSettings.Contains("listTask")) appSettings["listTask"] = listJob;
else appSettings.Add("listTask", listJob);
appSettings.Save();

List<myTodo> readList = appSettings["listTask"] as List<myTodo>;
```

Comment: I dont want to change a value that already exists, I want to be able to add two text box's with text blocks. I want to be able to have
if (appsettings.Contains("name"))
     {
       appsettings.Remove("name");
       appsettings.Add("name", TitleTextBox.Text);
     }


and

if (appsettings.Contains("title"))
     {
       appsettings.Remove("title");
       appsettings.Add("title", TitleTextBox.Text); //rename if already exists
     }

working at the same time

Comment: Wait as I understand - you want to change the value - if you remove it and then add the same type - you are changing it. I also Wonder what is the purpose of holding the same value in two places, but it may be needed if you want to change them somewhere else.

Comment: Hi Romasz, thank you for your answers. The point is to carry two items , like to-do-list. The first textbox is the name of the task, and the second textbox is the description of the task, for example Name: "Clean"  description: "clean room". When the button is pressed and saved to user can view it. Another page shows Textblock which is the title of the task. and the second text block carries the description of the task.

Comment: So that is why it is important to not change what the first key is. My view page, (second page) shows how to view both text block items, however does not show (i think because the if statement is not nested correctly)
if (appsettings.Contains("name")) { string content = appsettings["name"].ToString(); titleTextBlock.Text = content; 

if (appsettings.Contains("title")) {
                    string ingcontent = appsettings["title"].ToString(); //converts to string
                    TextBlock.Text = title; //shows  title in text block 
           }
            }

Comment: @user2903379 There are many ways to accomplish this task. Do you know how many items will your to-do-list have or you wish to add them? Do the task always have two strings - title, thing to do?

Comment: the app should have 3 parts of information; title, description, and length of time to complete. At the minute i only have two but when I find out how to add the second one then the third will be easy. The input are all TextBlocks. And the View task page is three text blocks also.

Comment: @user2903379 So wait a while - now I understand your problem

Comment: I have figured out my problem. The code you gave me worked, I just needed to figure out the View page. For future reference, it was the if statements that were stopping it from working. I had If appsetting contains "title" then display in textblock, but the other If statement was stopping it from working because it needed to work both if statements and the it was saying that If X happened then Y so Z (add title) never happened. 
I used If  "name"  && "title" convert both to string - to resolve this issue.

Comment: If you want the data to be preserved permanently for your app, then you can use ISS in the way of list or collection as @Romasz explained. Or if the data has to be preserved only till the app is in execution state, then consider using `PhoneApplicationService.Current.State` in the same way as you use ISS

Comment: @user2903379 Consider this List in your App - it can make your life much easier ;) Also when you ask on this site and if somebody solved your problem remember to mark the answer as a solution (green tick besides the answer). Happy coding and good luck.